# Ajax call in Zend 1.12 return 404

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I'm using a old version of Zend (Is impossible to upgrade), the version is 1.12.

I have this Jquery function

```
`var link = '<?php echo $this->route('ajax-getextras', 'bookings', 'default') ?>';
                    var direction = $(this).parent().attr('class');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: link,
                        data: $("#infoDisponibilidad").serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('.actions').html(data);
                            reviewBreadcrumbs(direction);
                        }
                    });`
```

And this work with ajaxGetextrasAction function, but when I try with a new ajax call

```
`var link = '<?php echo $this->route('ajax-getcapacidadisla', 'bookings', 'default') ?>';
            var direction = $(this).parent().attr('class');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: link,
                data: $("#infoDisponibilidad").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.actions').html(data);
                    reviewBreadcrumbs(direction);
                }
            });`
```

return 404, the function ajaxGetCapacidadIslaAction exists in the BookingsControlller

Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you check whether the route that should be called exists? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Where Can I define the route??? For example, ajax-getextras, the only result is in the file where do the Ajax Call.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if the name of the action is 'ajaxGetCapacidadIslaAction' the final endpoint shoul be 'ajax-get-gapacidad-isla' and not 'ajax-getcapacidadisla'